# Using Try-catch structure in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, codeigniter

I have never used Try-catch in my code before, but now I need to do it and it seems that I don't quite understand the way it works. I have data in a string which I get using explode:

```
$groupNumbers = array();
$str = $dataGroups['groups'];
$groupNumbers = explode(",", $str);
$count = count($groupNumbers);
```

Then I want to check if every element is numeric, and if it is I proceed with a database query, otherwise I want to abort the action ant return some error.

Here is what I'm doing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
    {
        try
        {
            is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i]);

        }
        catch (Exception $ex)
        {
            process_exception_to_json($ex);
        }
    }
```

and if evrery element is numeric I construc an active record to do SQL:

> $this->db->insert_batch('users_groups', $datas);

Obviously written like that, even if an element is not numeric the action is not aborted and I the insert_batch is still executed with unvalid values which is waht I want to avoid. What is the exact way of doing this, so I can get an exception, and abort the action at the same time.
Thanks

Leron

Comment: Put try catch outside the for loop. Ideally, you wouldn't want to rely on try-catch for validations though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because [`is_numeric`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/is_numeric) does not throws an exception but returns a value. It will never fail / throw an exception.

You would need to do it this way (just an example, I don't suggest it as it's superfluous):

```
try
{
    if (!is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i])) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Not numeric.');
    }

}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    process_exception_to_json($ex);
}
```

Instead create your own group numbers type:

```
try
{
    $groupNumbers = GroupNumbers::createFromString($dataGroups['groups']);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    process_exception_to_json($ex);
}
```

With the following type:

```
class GroupNumbers extends ArrayObject
{
    public function construct(Array $numbers) {
        foreach ($numbers as $number)
        {
            if (!is_numeric($number))
            {
                throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Not numeric "%s".', $number));
            }
        }
        parent::__construct($numbers);
    }
    public static function createFromString($string) {
        return new self(explode(",", $string));
    }
}
```

The string processing is now encapsulated, no more outer-loops and `GroupNumbers` does only instantiate if there are actual numbers in the string.

If you're not fluent with classes, you can have similar benefits as well with a procedural style. It's probably easier to understand (but pretty much the same):

```
try
{
    $groupNumbers = GroupNumbers_createFromString($dataGroups['groups']);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    process_exception_to_json($ex);
}

function GroupNumbers_createFromString($string)
{
    $numbers = explode(",", $string);
    foreach ($numbers as $number)
    {
        if (!is_numeric($number))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Not numeric "%s".', $number));
        }
    }
    return $numbers;
}
```

Comment: Lol a bit over mu level but gonna look through your code later. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of the class, you can create a function that returns the numeric array as well, e.g. something similar to the static function inlining the constructor. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`is_numeric` never throws any exceptions so your example doesn't do anything, this would work tho:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
{
    try
    {
        if (is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i]) !== true)
        {
            throw new Exception($groupNumbers[$i] . ' is not numeric');
        }
    }

    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        process_exception_to_json($ex);
    }
}
```

The following would accomplish (almost) the same thing:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
{
    if (is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i]) !== true)
    {
        process_exception_to_json($groupNumbers[$i] . ' is not numeric');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate, you dont need use `Exception` here

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; ++$i)
{
    if((int) $groupNumbers[$i] <= 0) {
        process_exception_to_json($groupNumbers[$i]);
        break; //optinal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something that actually throws an exception within the try block. is_numeric() will just return false, so that doesn't work. This will:

```
try {
    if (!is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i]) {
        throw new exception('Uh-oh!');
    } 
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    process_exception_to_json($ex);
}
```

Which is probably best done like this:

```
function checkNumbers($groupNumbers) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($groupNumbers); ++$i) {
        if (!is_numeric($groupNumbers[$i]) {
            throw new Exception('"'.$groupNumbers[$i]." is non-numeric!");
        } 
    }
}

try {
    checkNumbers($numbers);
    // Won't get this far if it throws an exception
    $this->db->insert_batch('users_groups', $numbers);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    process_exception_to_json($ex);
}
```

The exceptions can be very deeply nested within the code and the main benefit is that the error message is specific and will bubble up without you having to worry about lots of true or false values. You might have dozens of chained functions being called from checkNumbers() and whatever the error, it'll pop up in the catch block ready for you to send it to JSON.